# Handling session (dis)connected events using Spring Websocket support / Stomp

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket

Within the same app, sometimes I need to track websocket session (dis)connections and sometimes not.

In order to track `SessionConnectedEvent`s, I just pass some headers while connecting, such as in the following example:

```
stompClient.connect({
    companyId:1,
    messageType: 'BUSINESS_CASE_1' // all message sents using this session will be typed
}, frame => {
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/foo', response => {});
});
```

On server side, such events are easily intercepted using a listener and a `StompHeaderAccessor`:

```
public class SessionConnectedEventListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectedEvent event) {

        StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());           
        String messageType = StompUtils.getHeaderValue("messageType", sha);
        // handle business cases depending on the message type
    } 
}
```

It looks hacky, but it works.

Whereas on disconnection (`SessionDisconnectEvent`), I can't see anything but a `sessionId` within the `StompHeaderAccessor`. Not a single reference back to the original session/client information. :-(

1) Does there exist a better/cleaner way to differentiate session connected events than using headers on connection?

2) Is there a way to pass business data during session disconnection? So that I could handle different business logics depending on where in my app the disconnection occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass parameters on disconnect.

You can implement a simple map that is having the session id as a key and the value is an object holding the values you capture from the client on connection.

Comment: 2) Not particularly keen on that, mainly because it implies to store a kind of state somewhere, but thanks anyway.